# EUI64 and ipv6: how to use own EUI64 for IPv6 autoconfiguration

Tags: linux, suse, ipv6

As I heard the extended unique identifier (EUI-64) can be used as the lower 64 bits of a IPV6 address. How can I set my own EUI64 = ( IEEE_company_ID + manufacture_ID) on the interface on Linux SUSE SLES11 to use it for Lilnk Local and SLAAC generation of ipv6 address on that interface? 
Is it possible?
Or generation of LinkLocal and SLAAC address uses only MAC48’s EUI64!

Best wishes,
Ivan

Answer (score 1):

SLAAC uses the  EUI64 that is generated from the MAC48 to guarantee a unique address. You may have success with changing the EUI64 by changing the MAC48; however, you probably want to just manually assign an IP address.

Comment: Ok. I see. Thanks a lot. 
Yes, I can create my own ip address with EUI64 and set it as second Link Local. But I thought that it could be some procedure for Linux to set EUI64... 
Ivan